# how does iOS network stream socket detect network loss without keep alives

Tags: ios, sockets, network-programming

I have a socket server and have two separate client implementations. One which uses BSD sockets and one which uses iOS higher level stream socket APIs using the CFStreamCreatePairWithSocketToHost API.

When my machine loses connectivity (no side has called close - simply turn off wi-fi) - the native socket implementation is unable to detect this but the iOS socket stream detects this within seconds. From what I read people suggest that there should be application level keep-alives to detect loss reliably..

But I am curious how the iOS stream socket detects this because my server is the same for both and it doesn't send any keep alive.